# How to allocate memory in java?

Tags: java, android, performance, memory, optimization

Is there a way to allocate memory in java so as to simply make it unavailable? Perhaps the garbage collector would just clean it up preventing me from doing this?

If there is I'm intending to use it as a way to constrain the resources available to me while working on a game.

Comment: Create an object with a public static reference to it in some class. GC won't clean it while the reference exists (after the class is statically initialized it won't die until app ends)

Comment: And that object can be an array.

Comment: You don't need to constrain resources that way; most VM's have command line parameters or - in case of Android - monitoring capabilities to control/analyse memory allocation.

Comment: These are all good ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just create an arbitrary array and maintain a reference to it. The GC won't cleanup live objects.